# What is Firebase Analytics log events (not set) keyword

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm using firebase analytics on my android app.

There are some (not set) keywords on my dashboard.

What does (not set) mean?

Thanks for your answer.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is likely the value for a custom dimension (previously event parameter) that you've applied to some or all events being you're logging in your app via Google Analytics. There can be multiple reasons why a parameter might have the value of (not set) covered in this [help center article](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2820717?hl=en). Please take a look as the cause in this case is likely one of the reasons listed there.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will find the reason